# Rails: Select from multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, models

In my rails application i a have a job model

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :organization
```

and i want to drop-down a name list of all company name and organization name in the same field so I'm wondering if this is possible actually I was just using company name before i have added the organization, I have this code in my job form

```
<%= f.text_field :company_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Company.order(:name).map(&:name) },required: true %>
```

and this in my job model

```
def company_name
  company.try(:name)
end

def company_name=(name)
   self.company = Company.where(name: name).first_or_create
end
```

Comment: Put the logic in view is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the difference between Company and Organization. I'm assuming Company and Organization have no relation to each other. So you can just union the two sets.

```
<% companies_and_organizations = (Company.all.pluck(:name) + Organization.all.pluck(:name)).sort %>
<%= f.text_field :company_name, data: {autocomplete_source: companies_and_organizations}, required: true %>
```

Then I assume you only assign one or the other field. In this case creating a Company if the selected name does not match an existing Company or Organization:

```
def company_name
  (company || organization).try(:name)
end

def company_name=(name)
   company_or_organization = Organization.where(name: name).first
   company_or_organization ||= Company.where(name: name).first_or_create
   self.company = company_or_organization
end
```

Comment: Yes there is no relation between organization and company they are two different model. I will give your code a try but can you tell me if a record doesn't exist it will be created as a company or organization or both??

Comment: Note that I edited this (I missed `||` on the `where` checks). In the code I chose to create a Company if record doesn't exist. I don't know which you prefer to do; you can swap the Organization/Company `where` clauses. Just make sure you `first_or_create` the last one.

Comment: Also, in case you are wondering `.pluck(:name)` is like `.map(&:name)` (that you used) except that it only returns the one field from the database, rather than loading every record and instantiating an object. So a little performance improvement if you have lots of Companies or Organizations.